# How unity raycast prevent double jump problem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to prevent the player to double jump, for that I am using Raycast to check if the player is in the layer Floor. My solution works sometimes, but sometimes it allows the player to double jump.

This is my code:

```
void Movement()
{
    float movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    Vector3 playerVelocity = new Vector3(movement*speed, myRigidbody.velocity.y, speed);

    myRigidbody.velocity = playerVelocity;


    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space") && isGrounded)
    {
        Vector3 jumpVelocity = new Vector3(0f, jumpSpeed, 0f);
        myRigidbody.velocity += jumpVelocity;
        isGrounded = false;
        Debug.Log("floor:"+isGrounded);
        anim.SetInteger("AnimationPar", 3);
        myAudioSource.Stop();
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(jumpSound,transform.position, volumeSoundEffects);
    }
    else if (isGrounded && !myAudioSource.isPlaying && !levelFinished)
    {
        myAudioSource.Play();
    }
    if (!isGrounded)
    {
        IsGrounded();
    }

}

void IsGrounded()
{        
    RaycastHit hit;
    int mask = 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Floor");

    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out hit, 0.01f, mask))
    {
        //Debug.Log("Is touching floor");
        isGrounded = true;
        Debug.Log("floot:" + isGrounded);
        anim.SetInteger("AnimationPar", 1);
        if (!myAudioSource.isPlaying)
        {
            myAudioSource.Play();
        }            
    }
}
```

The Movement method is called in Update. I think that maybe the IsGrounded method is called to fast and the player is still to close to the floor.

Comment: I usually just use a timer. float nextJumpTime; nextJumpTime = Time.time + 0.5f; if(Time.time >= nextJumpTime) Jump(); then, if space is pressed, IsGrounded() etc. is called again

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to prevent double jump is using a counter instead of raycast, it really makes everything easy. put a counter in this portion of the code:

```
  if (Input.GetKeyDown("space") && isGrounded && counter <2)
        {


  Vector3 jumpVelocity = new Vector3(0f, jumpSpeed, 0f);
counter++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Im unable to debug your code at this time, but another way you could do it is using OnCollisionEnter and OnCollisionExit
You can detect all things your players collides with, if one of them is the Floor then its likely hes grounded. But it would be possible to touch the floor on the side of the player while falling, to avoid this use the grounded method agian. You said it does work but sometimes fails. So try something like:

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col) 
{
   if(col.gameobject.layer == LayerMask.NameToLayer("Floor") && IsGrounded())
   {
       isGrounded = true;
   }
}
void OnCollisionExit (Collision col) 
{
   if(col.gameobject.layer == LayerMask.NameToLayer("Floor") && !IsGrounded())
   {
       isGrounded = false;
   }
}
```

Thats untested code so im not 100% sure if it will work. The Exit may not work since IsGrounded may still be able to raycast to the ground. But if you handle your layers/collision in your levels right then you can remove the IsGrounded calls entirely.

This isnt the perfect solution by far but it might work.